# Sodom and Gomorrah and the sinful nature of Lot and his daughters

Tags: genesis

In Genesis 19:30-38 Lot was tricked into getting drunk by both daughters who then slept with him. Both daughters were impregnated, ultimately forming new groups of people. What was the daughters' motivation for doing so?  Isn't incest a sin? Isn't extreme drunkenness a sin? Trickery? Why does the Torah not seem to address or condemn these sins addressed?

Comment: Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! We are glad you are here - and thank you for taking a moment to check out the site [tour]. You may also with to read how this site is a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) than others. This is a great first question. If you see any questions you would like to answer, you will want to be aware that we have [certain guidelines and a recommended format](https://goo.gl/rDWUdw) for doing so - namely you will want to [show your work](https://goo.gl/JOW5ib) - so you may want to check these out too. Again, Welcome!

Comment: Answerers might wish to consult the work of Johanna Stiebert on this question. See: *[Fathers and Daughters in the Hebrew Bible](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nu51Fp8JnZQC&printsec=frontcover)* (OUP, 2013); and *[First-Degree Incest and the Hebrew Bible: Sex in the Family](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cUDqDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)* (Bloomsbury T & T Clark, 2016) -- both of which discuss the case of Lot and his daughters.

Answer (score 3):

**What was the daughters' motivation**

We see repeatedly in the Old Testament that it was considered important for a man to have male descendants. Even when a man died without an heir, his brother was required to marry the wife so that there would at least be a closely related heir. We see this  in [Genesis chapter 38](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-38/), where Er died without an heir. Although Er was wicked, his father, Judah, told Er's brother Onan to have sex with the widow Tamar, but Onan refused.  So great was Tamar's need for a son from the family line that she dressed as a sacred prostitute and tricked Judah into having sex and conceiving a child.

The story of Lot's daughters is similar to the story of Tamar, and the motivation was the same. Their father, Lot, was old and was reaching the age when he was unlikely to have any more children. As his only children, the daughters wanted him to have male descendants, but there was "not a man in the earth to come in unto us" so they conspired to have children by their own father. Each had a son, called Moab and Benammi.

**Condemnation these sins**

There is indirect condemnation of these sins, because the Moabites and the Ammonites, respectively the putative descendants of  Moab and Benammi, were frequent enemies of the Israelites. Their descent from drunkenness, trickery and incest was good reason for the Israelites to hold the Moabites and the Ammonites in contempt.

Answer (score -1):

according to Jews philosophy on that time there were only the "seven commands/laws of Noah".
The seven Noahide laws as traditionally enumerated are the following:
1    Do not deny God.
2    Do not blaspheme God.
3    Do not murder.
4    Do not engage in illicit sexual relations.
5    Do not steal.
6    Do not eat from a live animal.
7    Establish courts/legal system to ensure obedience to the law.
(read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah).

So as you can see - drinking wine is not a sin (actually till that day).

Moreover -  from that act two nations came to the world - and one of that nations (Moab) brought us king David (Ruth was Moabian) himself...